# HttpUtility.UrlEncode() and Server.UrlEncode() are not encoding the URL in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, hyperlink, itemtemplate

I am trying to encode the url using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`,
but not able to make it work. `HyperLink` control is in the
template field of gridview.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

I have tried changing the target application and by adding
`System.Web` reference to project but still not able to Encode
the url.

Please guide me.

Following is part of my code:-

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkDetailsPage" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/YellowPages/YellowDetailView.aspx?CustomerId={0}",HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("CustomerId").ToString())) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Server.UrlEncode()` instead. Why do you need to encode your CustomerID?!

Comment: How does your CustomerID look like?

Comment: this way http://localhost:54892/PreHostingCopy/YellowPages/YellowDetailView.aspx?CustomerId=7410

Comment: Is this the CustomerID, or the whole Url?!

Comment: I don't think you need to url encode the CustomerId, because it is an integer number, being passed as a url parameter.

Comment: But i dont want to display the customerid.

Comment: Aha. That is another thing. `UrlEncode()` is doing fine, and encoding an integer results in the same number! url encoding is not what you need. You should either encrypt the CustomerId, or put it somewhere user can not see. `Session` is a good place, for example. Put the CustomerId in `Session` and redirect to `YellowDetailView.aspx`. There, read the CustomerId from `Session` and go ahead.

Comment: All I found on Server.URLEncode() is this and it seems it wasn't moved to .NET 4.5. Am I wrong? What namespace does it use? I'm having trouble using this.

Comment: Wrong. It is right there. Tell me what you are using (Web Forms, MVC, ...) and where (show us some code) you are trying to call it?